# Wordpress Elementor - Click on button to copy a text to clipboard

Tags: html, copy, clipboard, elementor

I am using Elementor Pro in Wordpress.

I would like to create a button that allows to copy a simple text to clipboard (which will be the coupon code - always the same). This way the customer can simply paste it on the checkout page.

[screenshot of button on Elementor page builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljVUx.png)

I have read about how to copy the URL link when clicking on the button but not how to copy a simple text.

Thank you for your help in advance,
GT

I tried by adding an HTML Element but I have no idea of what text to put in there.